# Break the calculation for a dollar

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

3 friend went to a coffee shop.

They ordered their coffee, had it and enjoyed their time.

Waiter came with a **bill of \$30.**

So they decided **to pay \$10 each.**

Waiter **gave them \$5 in return as a discount.**

Now they **took \$1 each and gave \$2 as a tip to waiter.**

That means coffee **cost them \$9 per friend** and that is **9x3=27 dollars.**

And they **gave \$2 to waiter** which makes a total of **27+2=29 dollars.**

---

> ***But they initially gave a total of \$30.***

---

**Where did a dollar go?**

Comment: @Xylius nope it is very different. please check the answer from Jasen.

Comment: Same thing really.. Just different situation and different numbers, but I'll leave it to other people to moderate and vote

Comment: @Xylius yes that's better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They spent `$25` on coffee and gave `$2` to the waiter,

> total cost `$27` that and the three dollars change they kept makes `$30`

> Adding the tip to the total makes no sense the tip was part of the total.

Comment: exactly you have got it right

Comment: Or simply "That means coffee cost them  \$$9$ per friend" is a false statement; the coffee cost them \$$\frac{25}{3}$ per friend.